# Open Problem in Fixed Point Theory [Prize]

Tags: calculus, analysis, economics

This open problem appeared on the bulletins of Evans Hall at Berkeley this week.

I hope this doesn't violate StackExchange policy (**the solution carries a $500 prize**), but I thought why not re-post it here!

---

**Definition 1** Let $x$ and $y$ be i.i.d. random variables distributed according to $F$ with continuous support over $R^{+}$.  Let continuously differentiable function $g(x, y)$ exhibit:

**1.** Symmetry:  $\forall x, y \in [0, \infty), g(x,y) = g(y, x).$

**2** Synergy: $\forall x, y \in [0, \infty), g(x, y) > x+y.$

**3** Increasing Differences: $\forall x, y \in [0, \infty), \frac{d}{dx}g(x,y) > 1.$

**4** Initial Coincidence: $\forall x \in [0, \infty), g(x,0) = x.$

**Conjecture 2** (Fixed Point)

$\exists \gamma \in (\frac{1}{2} , 1) : \gamma = E[\frac{x}{x+y} : g(x, y)\gamma > x$ AND $g(x,y)(1-\gamma) > y]. $

**Remark 3**

Conditions 1 and 2 on $g$ are required.  Optional conditions 3 and 4 reduce difficulty but a solution that does not require them would be superior.

**Remark 4**

Contest ends on 5/31/13.  If more than one correct solution is submitted, the first will be selected.  If a counterexample is discovered, a prize will also be awarded.

**Contact 5**

Justin Tumlinson (Ifo Institute for Econonmic Research at Munich) tumlinson@ifo.de
John Morgan (U.C. Berkeley) morgan@haas.berkeley.edu

Comment: 2. and 4. do not go well together...  Also, what does the final "$> g$" mean in the conjecture?

Comment: I reread the explanation; you are correct my friend- should be a $y$

Comment: Should post at mathoverflow.net as well.

Comment: I believe the relevant paper is this one: http://poseidon01.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=240069002121076000083002122119066075017073054032033092074008007074008127004025071069126000025041062008124019124065116093119122007080012013002113090124031028099093046036044017095026073030004025100113125&EXT=pdf